# Why do I get infinite recursion with getattr(), but not with __dict__[]?

Tags: python, django, recursion, descriptor

I am trying to implement a custom Django model field (inspired by [this blog post](http://blog.kevinastone.com/django-model-descriptors.html)) and while my code runs fine, I was intrigued by the following line of code:

```
value = instance.__dict__[self.field_name]
```

It seems to me that this is just an ugly way of calling [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr). Hence, I changed this line to the following:

```
value = getattr(instance, self.field_name)
```

I expected that the code would run the same. It doesn't, because now I get an infinite recursion error:

```
RuntimeError at /admin/testapp/testmodel/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Why do I get infinite recursion when using `getattr()`, but not when using `__dict__[]`?

--

Edit: here is an example model definition from the linked blog post:

```
from django.db import models

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
```

Comment: Could you post the class of `instance`?

Comment: Yep, I added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getattr tries to get the attribute in any possible way. This includes calling `__get__`. If you use getattr in a function that is called by getattr (with the same arguments) you will end in an infinite loop. Directly accessing `__dict__` circumvents this "problem".